# How to fix "val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00" in categorical classification?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning, I have 3 classes to classify, when I train my model I observed that my **"val_loss > val_accuracy "**   means  my model is overfitting how can I fix this? also I get **"val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00"**  this way. Initially I have kept my epoch to low. I have less data to train a model.

````
import tensorflow as tf           
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, image
import numpy as np
import os
from pathlib import Path
country  = "armenia"
cwd = os.getcwd()
print("cwd",cwd)
save_path = r'E://paymentz//'+country+'/'
abc  = os.listdir(r'E:/paymentz/'+country+'/training')
print("list of subfolders in directory:",abc)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 2, 2, input_shape = ( 64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(output_dim= 64, activation='relu' ))
output_dim = os.listdir(r'E:/paymentz/'+country+'/training')
print(len(output_dim))
output_dim = len(output_dim)
model.add(Dense(output_dim , activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])
batch_size = 16
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True,
                               rotation_range = 360)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r'E:/paymentz/'+country+'/training',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size= batch_size,
                                            class_mode='categorical')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r'E:/paymentz/'+country+'/testing',
                                        target_size= (64, 64),
                                        batch_size= batch_size,
                                        class_mode='categorical')
training_path = Path(fr'E://paymentz//{country}//training')
training_png_count = len(list(training_path.rglob('*.png')))
training_jpg_count = len(list(training_path.rglob('*.jpg')))
training_jpeg_count = len(list(training_path.rglob('*.jpeg')))
          
training_count = training_png_count + training_jpg_count + training_jpeg_count
print("training_count ", training_count)
            
testing_path = Path(fr'E://paymentz//{country}//testing')
testing_png_count = len(list(testing_path.rglob('*.png')))
testing_jpg_count = len(list(testing_path.rglob('*.jpg')))
testing_jpeg_count = len(list(testing_path.rglob('*.jpeg')))
            
testing_count = testing_png_count + testing_jpg_count + testing_jpeg_count
print("testing_count ", testing_count)              

steps_per_epoch = (training_count// batch_size )
print("steps_per_epoch", steps_per_epoch)
validation_steps = ( testing_count // batch_size )
print("validation_steps", validation_steps) 
    
model.fit_generator(
      training_set,
      validation_data = test_set,
      samples_per_epoch = training_count, 
      epochs = 15,
      validation_steps = validation_steps,
      steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch)
print("training done.")
score = model.fit(test_set)
score= model.evaluate_generator(test_set)
print("test_set ",score)
#score= model.evaluate_generator(training_set)
#print("training_set ", score)
#if score[0] < 0.05 and score [1] < .85:
save_path = r'E:/paymentz/'+country+'/'
model.save(save_path+country+'.model')
model.save(save_path+country+'.model.h5')
#model.save("StatewiseDLmodel.model.h5")
print("model saved")

abc  = os.listdir(r'E:/paymentz/'+country+'/training')

model_path = r''+country+'model.h5'

#model = tf.keras.models.load_model(country+'.model.h5')
print("model trained to:",score)```
````

Comment: There are several issues: why are you fitting on you test set? (```score = model.fit(test_set)```. You cannot compare loss and accuracy like that "val_loss > val_accuracy ".

Comment: i have removed score = model.fit(test_set) this but still i am getting an issue ```Epoch 25/25
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 166ms/step - loss: 0.6426 - accuracy: 0.8182 - val_loss: 1.2964 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00```

Comment: This is not something I can help you with. This depends on how large your test dataset is, how good your network learns, how large your training data set is, and so on. Is there a specific problem that is reproducible?

Comment: my training data set consists of 40 images and my test dataset condidts of 11 images only

Comment: my loss and accuracy ```[4.859940528869629, 0.07692307978868484]```

Comment: you have input size 64 64 , you are using strides of 2 and 3 followed by maxpooling layers plus dropout of 0.5 which is quite high, all these factors will lead loosing almost ever info from image so the overfitting, try to use only pooling layers and 1 stride in conv layers or stirde 2 in conv layers, drop less neurons

Comment: let me know if this works

Comment: see this  what i am getting```[1.0459357500076294, 0.13793103396892548]```

Comment: ```    model = Sequential()

       model.add(Convolution2D(8, 2, 2, input_shape = ( 64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

          model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

          model.add(Dropout(0.3))```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you fitting your model again on the test set?

```
print("training done.")
score = model.fit(test_set) # this should be predict.
score= model.evaluate_generator(test_set)
print("test_set ",score)
```

remove the following line and try again.

```
score = model.fit(test_set)
```

Comment: Epoch 15/15
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 193ms/step - loss: 0.7777 - accuracy: 0.6562 - val_loss: 1.1908 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Comment: i have removed but still i am getting this `val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00` @praveen kumar